# How To Purge Cache in W3 Total Cache Automatically?

Tags: wordpress, caching, purge, w3-total-cache

I am Using W3 Total cache plugin for WordPress. My post has one table which updates every minute/hour. But as I do caching, the server does not serves latest version, instead it displays cached copy to the visitor. How can I purge cache every 30 minutes automatically so that it shows latest version of the post at after every 30 minutes?
I have already tried inserting this code in functions.php file but its not purging cache every 1h, instead it does 2-3h later.

```
function w3_flush_cache( ) {
    $w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all();
}

// Schedule Cron Job Event

function w3tc_cache_flush() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'w3_flush_cache' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'w3_flush_cache' );    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As nobody answered yet:

> The ‘interval’ is a number in seconds of when the cron job should run.
> So for ‘hourly’ the time is HOUR_IN_SECONDS (60 60 or 3600). For
> ‘monthly’, the value would be MONTH_IN_SECONDS (30 24 60 60 or
> 2592000).

See [wp_get_schedules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_schedules/) reference.

So for every 30 minutes you should use something like 30*60 = 1800.

```
wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 1800, 'w3_flush_cache' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your server or have shared hosting, you can set up cron job too very easily.

I am running this command `wp w3-total-cache flush all` once per week. To set the timing interval for how often you want to run the command you can use a cron expression generator [like this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html). Every 30 minutes would be `* 0 0 ? * * *` (runs at exactly 00 and 30 mins past the hour)